# How do you detect if a given dataset has multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, normality-assumption, discriminant-analysis

I'm looking at Fisher's LDA on various datasets on UCI ML repository and trying to see where LDA might perform badly. One reason I can think of is if the data distribution is not a multi-variate normal distribution. This is from the fact I read in a book where you apply LDA on multivariate normal distribution. Is that thought process correct? When might LDA give bad results?

Comment: I don't quite follow the phrasing of your question. Fisher's LDA assume the data *are* multivariate normal, which would be violated if there were, eg, some binary variables as well.

Comment: I think you are missing a "not" before "a multi-variate normal" distribution, so I added that. Feel free to change it back if I've messed things up.

Comment: If you Google "LDA and logistic regression" you will find a lot of papers on this e.g. [Pohar et al](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pub/mz/mz1.1/pohar.pdf)

Comment: @gung I'm looking at ways to see if before applying LDA can I do something to see if data is in the form of multi-variate normal distribution. I might be getting my phrasing incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

By definition the random vector $X$ is multivariate normal if **all** linear combinations $a^T X$ have some (univariate) normal distribution.  So one idea to test multivariate normality is to search among the vectors $a$ for one such that $a^T X$ is definitely not normal.  That is the idea behind pp, projection pursuit methods. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_pursuit

Answer (score 0):

A fast way of examining whether your data set is Gaussian distributed or not is to plot a histogram for each variable of your data set (if the dimensionality is small), or simply just calculate the sample skewness and kurtosis to check if they are Gaussian distributed. A Gaussian distributed data set will have skewness = 0 and kurtosis =3.